# Entity SQL DateDiff function

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I  I build select and where condition against an entity ObjectSet class using
ObjectQuery.

```
  ObjectQuery<DbDataRecord> query = context.TestEnt.Select("it.BuySell, "
                        + "it.DepoTerm").Where("Datediff(day,it.RunDateTime,'22-11-2012')=0" );

                var a = query.ToList();
                foreach (var tmp in a)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(tmp["BuySell"].ToString());
                }
```

I would like to use datediff function in my where contition ,
How can I do it ?

Comment: i am not sure,but is not possible in entity framework (possible in Linq). but on question, are you using Linq.Dynamic class too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = context.TestEnt
                   .Where("DiffDays(it.RunDateTime,'22-11-2012')=0" );
                   .Select("it.BuySell, it.DepoTerm")
```

It is possible that you will have to call `CreateDataTime` on your string passed data to make it work. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563.aspx) is list of all supported date functions in ESQL.

You can also use Linq-to-entities:

```
var query = context.TestEnt
                   .Where(x => SqlFunctions.DateDiff("day", x.RunDateTime,'22-11-2012') == 0)
                   .Select(x => new { x.BuySell, x.DepoTerm });
```

Comment: Unfortunately "DiffDays(it.RunDateTime,'22-11-2012')=0" ) does not work

Answer (score 0):

The ESQL function `DiffDays` does work, but it's fiddly to get it right.  You have to cast the string to a `DateTime`; however, since the text is converted to SQL using the `CreateQuery<>` method, you need to cast to `System.DateTime` or else the query will fail at runtime.

Try this:

```
ObjectQuery<DbDataRecord> query = context.TestEnt.Select("it.BuySell, it.DepoTerm")
    .Where("DiffDays(it.[RunDateTime],cast('22-11-2012' as System.DateTime))=0");

var a = query.ToList();
foreach (var tmp in a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(tmp["BuySell"].ToString());
}
```